"Error: Cannot Find index.html - Troubleshooting Assistance Needed"
I ran  Npm start and got this error Could not find a required file.
Name: index.html
Searched in: E:\Abubakar\Usage\my-app\public  , even though my index . html is public folder  it is still saying that .
I did Npm start and was expecting it to run without errors but it gave this error'Could not find a required file.
Name: index.html
Searched in: E:\Abubakar\Usage\my-app\public

I got same error before. Make sure index.html is exactly named right (lowercase matters). Also check if its in public folder. Maybe you need reinstall node_modules, delete node_modules and run npm install again. Hope this help.
